# How to change this bar chart as months order?

Tags: reactjs, bar-chart, recharts

This is code of generate Bar chat using recharts in react.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { BarChart, Bar, Cell, XAxis, YAxis, CartesianGrid, Tooltip, Legend, ResponsiveContainer } from 'recharts';

const MainChart = (props) => {
[
{month: 'January', total: 0},
{month: 'August', total: 12040},
{month: 'September', total: 2765},
{month: 'October', total: 63995},
{month: 'November', total: 13825},
{month: 'December', total: 0},
]const [data, setData] = useState([]);

}
  return (
<ResponsiveContainer width="100%" height="90%" >
      <BarChart width={150} height={40} data={data} >
        <XAxis dataKey="month" />

        <Bar dataKey="total" fill="#8884d8" />
      </BarChart>
    </ResponsiveContainer>
  );
};

export default MainChart;
```

Chart shows as
[image]

But january is 2024 and other months belongs to 2023.

I want to show it August, September, October, November,December, January. How to do this?

I have tried changing order of data. But it not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To display the months in the desired order ('August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December', 'January'), you can use the data array and reorder the months based on your requirement. You can create a new array or modify the existing one to rearrange the months in the desired order.

```
 const [data, setData] = useState([
    { month: 'January', total: 0 },
    { month: 'August', total: 12040 },
    { month: 'September', total: 2765 },
    { month: 'October', total: 63995 },
    { month: 'November', total: 13825 },
    { month: 'December', total: 0 },
  ]);

  // Or you have the unique key to identify the order or want 
  const orderedMonths = ['August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December', 'January'];

  // Reorder the data array based on the desired month order or unique key
  const reorderedData = orderedMonths.map((month) => data.find((item) => item.month === month));

  return (
    <ResponsiveContainer width="100%" height="90%">
      <BarChart width={150} height={40} data={reorderedData}>
        <XAxis dataKey="month" />
        <Bar dataKey="total" fill="#8884d8" />
      </BarChart>
    </ResponsiveContainer>
  );
```